# php how create new tabs inside the current browser window instead open new browser window?

Tags: php, tabs

I'm looking for a method so that by clicking on a link in the current window of my web page I will generate a tab within the current window instead of opening a new browser window, and that this new tab has the option of being able to close (similar to an excel file where when creating a new sheet a tab is added at the bottom but have an x ​​to close the tab). It must be flexible to create an infinite number of tabs so that depending on what is needed, the user can have several pages open at the same time and close them when they are no longer needed. I'm not sure if I should use tabs or iframes. what should i do or use? regards

Comment: like this: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ ?

Comment: It's really a GUI/framework type of thing you are asking. This can be done with many ways and using all kinds of libraries or full frameworks. I'd say you need to take a look of the available libraries and frameworks and also your other needs. It sounds somewhat complicated, so I would assume you're better off with using some full framework which offers other helpers too, not just making "tabs".

Comment: So, I just want to see if I understand you correctly... Is this correct: you want a mini web-browser inside one tab. This would be similar to a proxy site, or a website that allows you to access other websites through an iFrame. And unfortunately, that's essentially what you would be forced to do. There is no great way to do what you want to do unless you essentially just do the same thing as proxy servers (showing other websites on their own site), but add tabs to it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side but you can still kind open in a new tab/window.
It mostly depends on how the user configures their browser but you could just add `target="_blank"` to all of your `<a>` tags. For instance this link:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target" target="_blank">FollowTheHrefToAnExample</a>
```

Alternatively you can use javascript:

```
window.open(destinationURL, '_blank').focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i didnt comment that all the urls i want to open are from my own website, so i think the way is about create frameworks, where can i find examples? Greetings